# Linux find command explanation

Tags: linux, find

Can someone explain me what does this command do and if I want to try the same thing using git, how should I modify this command?

```
find . -name CVS -print -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command looks in your current working directory for any directories or files named "CVS" and prints the full path. Then executes a forced recursive removal for each result returned by the find command.

Since there is no filetype present in the name, this command will remove any directory, within your current working directory, named CVS, including all subdirectories and files housed within.